# How can i fix error for npm package k6 in nodejs project

Tags: node.js, json, performance, testing, k6

I have a project to be able to call the scenario implemented with k6 by api and give the value vu and iteration in the body.
now i have a package.js with this code:

```
    {
        "name": "k6-api",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "main": "index.js",
        "scripts": {
            "start": "node src/index.js",
            "swagger": "swagger-jsdoc -o swagger.json"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "express": "^4.18.2",
            "k6": "^0.0.0",
            "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8"
        },
        "type": "module",
        "devDependencies": {
            "@types/express": "^4.17.21"
        }
    }
```

and I install k6 and I can display version 0.49.0 but when I run project with npm start I get an error.

$ npm start

> k6-api@1.0.0 start
> node src/index.js

node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:214
const resolvedOption = FSLegacyMainResolve(packageJsonUrlString, packageConfig.main, baseStringified);
^

Error: Cannot find package '/home/snapp/Documents/service/node_modules/k6/package.json' imported from /home/snapp/Documents/service/src/utils/runTest.js
at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:214:26)
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:832:14)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:918:18)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1148:11)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v21.7.1